# SED replacing only 1st occurrence of Pattern even with "g" flag

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed, sh

I have a string where I want to replaced existing version no. string with new value but sed is replacing only 1st occurrence of version no string not all.

I have tried with g flag also i.e.

**Input**

```
Old_Version="1.0.0"
New_Version="2.0.0"
SEARCH_STRING="Unique String"


echo 'versionString =  isMajor? "Major Version 1.0.0" : "Minor Version 1.0.0"; // Unique String' |
sed -e "s/$Old_Version\(.*$SEARCH_STRING\)/$New_Version\1/g"
```

**Output**

```
versionString =  isMajor? "Major Version 2.0.0" : "Minor Version 1.0.0"; // Unique String
```

As you can see above that it is replacing only 1st version no but not second i.e.

**Desired Output**

```
versionString =  isMajor? "Major Version 2.0.0" : "Minor Version 2.0.0"; // Unique String
```

Also, search pattern string can be any unique text in line. It need not be last text/comment in line.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IT's because the 2nd instance of the "old" version is captured in the `.*` part of your regex.

I assume you want to limit replacing for lines containing the search string, in which case you would write

```
$ input='versionString =  isMajor? "Major Version 1.0.0" : "Minor Version 1.0.0"; // Unique String'
$ sed -e "/$SEARCH_STRING/ s/$Old_Version/$New_Version/g" <<<"$input"
```

```
versionString =  isMajor? "Major Version 2.0.0" : "Minor Version 2.0.0"; // Unique String
```

That says "only for lines matching the SEARCH_STRING, perform the s///g command"

---

Note that dot is a regex special character. Since you want to match literal dots, the dots in the Old_Version should be escaped, otherwise you could match something like "19090"

```
$ sed -e "/$SEARCH_STRING/ s/${Old_Version//./\\.}/$New_Version/g" <<<"$input"
# ...........................^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That uses the shell's parameter substitution syntax to inject backslashes before the dots.

Also, add word boundaries to avoid matching "21.0.0" or "1.0.02"

```
$ sed -e "/$SEARCH_STRING/ s/\\<${Old_Version//./\\.}\\>/$New_Version/g" <<<"$input"
# ...........................^^^.....................^^^
```